# How can I stop Express.js from causing a file to be downloaded in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the browser, I'm trying to preview a file (Word document) by using an iframe:

```
<iframe style="float:right;" src = "/ViewerJS/#../demo/ohm2013.odp" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

(if it's relevant, this is the library: http://viewerjs.org)

On the server side, I'm retrieving the file from a stream (MongoDB/GridFS) and then piping it to the res object. The relevant code is:

```
res.contentType("application/msword");
readstream.pipe(res);
```

On the browser side, this downloads the file locally instead of previewing it.

How can I get the browser to preview my file instead of downloading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only suggest to the browser what to do with the file; ultimately it's up to the browser and its configuration.

I think the default behavior is to try to show the content inline, but maybe not for certain types; you can explicitly suggest showing it inline by sending the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header in the response with the value `inline`, using [`res.set`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set) *before* sending any data:

```
res.set("Content-Disposition", "inline");
```

This **suggests** to the browser that it show the file inline rather than offering to save it. But again, the browser still may to offer to save it instead.